# How to enrich hierarchical data in list of lists with parent and child ids?

Tags: python, hierarchical-data

Suppose we have some hierarchical data, represented in a list of lists:

```
list = [
    ['US', 'Central', 'Louisiana', 'Monroe']
    ['US', 'Central', 'Texas', 'Midland']
    ['US', 'Pacific', 'California', 'East Palo Alto']
    ['UK', 'Coastside', 'Sussex', 'Brighton']
]
```

And we we like to add hierarchical id's to each item in form of a tree structure, so to achieve this:

```
list = [
    [(key1,'US',None), (key3,'Central',key1), (key6,'Louisiana',key3), (key10,'Monroe',key6)]
    [(key1,'US',None), (key3,'Central',key1), (key7,'Texas',key3), (key11,'Midland',key7]
    [(key1,'US',None), (key4,'Pacific',key1), (key8,'California',key4), (key12,'East Palo Alto',key8]
    [(key2,'UK',None), (key5,'Coastside',key2), (key9,'Sussex',key5) (key13,'Brighton',key9]
]
```

Is this it possible to do with some elegant python construct? I started doing this manually in Excel, but since the initial data structure is massive, this seems to be a never ending task...

Comment: yes it is possible by Python !!!

Comment: Iterate through the outer list and (sub)iterate through the elements of each sublist and "enrich" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly two tasks:

1. Key Generation for each word.
2. Custom Conversion from Keys and ur list.

**Key Generation:**  I used simple logic to generate keys for each word, I am iterating list by each item and generate unique key for each word in item by using count method.

Note: You can change this logic according to ur requirement.

**Custom Conversion:** Now we have Keys and List, Generate new item of list, here main key is add previous key to each word of new item, so used `pre_key` variable to store previous key of previous word and set default value to `None`.

### **Demo:**

**Input:**

```
mylist = [
    ['US', 'Central', 'Louisiana', 'Monroe'],
    ['US', 'Central', 'Texas', 'Midland'],
    ['US', 'Pacific', 'California', 'East Palo Alto'],
    ['UK', 'Coastside', 'Sussex', 'Brighton'],
]
```

**Code:**

```
def keyGenerator(mylist):
    result_keys = {}
    count = 1
    for item in mylist:
        for i in item:
            if i not in result_keys:
                result_keys[i] = "key%03d"%count
                count += 1

    return result_keys


def customConversion(mylist, result_keys):
    new_mylist = []
    for item in mylist:
        new_item = []
        pre_key = None
        for i in item:
            current_key = result_keys[i]
            new_item.append((current_key, i, pre_key))
            pre_key = current_key

        new_mylist.append(new_item)

    return new_mylist


mylist = [
    ['US', 'Central', 'Louisiana', 'Monroe'],
    ['US', 'Central', 'Texas', 'Midland'],
    ['US', 'Pacific', 'California', 'East Palo Alto'],
    ['UK', 'Coastside', 'Sussex', 'Brighton'],
]

#- Generate Key to each Word.
result_keys = keyGenerator(mylist)
# Custom Conversion
new_mylist = customConversion(mylist, result_keys)

print "Result:"
for i in new_mylist:
    print i
```

**Result:**

```
Result:
[('key001', 'US', None), ('key002', 'Central', 'key001'), ('key003', 'Louisiana', 'key002'), ('key004', 'Monroe', 'key003')]
[('key001', 'US', None), ('key002', 'Central', 'key001'), ('key005', 'Texas', 'key002'), ('key006', 'Midland', 'key005')]
[('key001', 'US', None), ('key007', 'Pacific', 'key001'), ('key008', 'California', 'key007'), ('key009', 'East Palo Alto', 'key008')]
[('key010', 'UK', None), ('key011', 'Coastside', 'key010'), ('key012', 'Sussex', 'key011'), ('key013', 'Brighton', 'key012')]
```

Comment: thank you very very much for your complete solution. This is by far more, than I would have expected. Will try it tomorrow and give feedback.